# Run multiple INSERT statements to same table sequentially in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

In MySQL, I am trying to run multiple INSERT commands into the same table sequentially.
Each insert command takes an hour due to huge amount of data.So I want to run it one by one automatically.

For ex.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
INSERT INTO tableA (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
INSERT INTO tableA (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
INSERT INTO tableA (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
```

Should this be fine?
Do I need to commit after each insert?

Comment: What do you mean by huge?

Comment: 7 crore rows for each insert

Comment: On at a time inserts isn't going to be quick - I suggest you chop into chunks of 1000 and insert them in a transaction. Out of curiosity how is all that data delivered to you?

Comment: I have set up pipelines: redshift -> S3 -> RDS

Can you please share some more details on the chopping?